# Groovy - map without assigned to any variable

Tags: grails, dictionary, groovy

I am using grails framework and there is these line codes in service groovy file. I see in this code, it look like map had been implemented but I don't understand how it will work without it being assigned to any variable in this file.

```
class ApprovalHeaderLEADEDService extends ApprovalHeaderService {
    def generateTable(ApprovalHeader ah,BondingDiagram bd){

        def waferMountOrientation= findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"WaferMountOrientation");
        def sawForModels = findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"SawForModels");
        def sawBladeType1= findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"SawBladeType1");

        [   
            waferMountOrientation:waferMountOrientation,
            sawForModels:sawForModels,
            sawBladeType1:sawBladeType1

        ]
    }
```

I expect a map would look like this

```
def map = [waferMountOrientation:waferMountOrientation, sawForModels:sawForModels, sawBladeType1:sawBladeType1]
```

Could anyone explain to me how this will work or suggest me any reference where I can read about this kind of map case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
def generateTable(ApprovalHeader ah,BondingDiagram bd){

    def waferMountOrientation= findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"WaferMountOrientation");
    def sawForModels = findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"SawForModels");
    def sawBladeType1= findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"SawBladeType1");

    [   
        waferMountOrientation:waferMountOrientation,
        sawForModels:sawForModels,
        sawBladeType1:sawBladeType1

    ]
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
def generateTable(ApprovalHeader ah,BondingDiagram bd){

    def waferMountOrientation= findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"WaferMountOrientation");
    def sawForModels = findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"SawForModels");
    def sawBladeType1= findApprovalHeaderKitName(ah,bd,"SawBladeType1");

    def someMap = [   
        waferMountOrientation:waferMountOrientation,
        sawForModels:sawForModels,
        sawBladeType1:sawBladeType1

    ]
    return someMap
}
```

A more simple example demonstrating the same thing (all of the following methods behave the same way):

```
def someMethod() {
    42
}

def someMethod() {
    return 42
}

def someMethod() {
    def value = 42
    value
}

def someMethod() {
    def value = 42
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's the return value of the function.

http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_optional_return_keyword